# Carousel inside modal body displaying all the images

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on a mini bootstrap project. The project has 3 parts: modal, carousel, and carousel within modal. Code for modal and carousel is running as per the plan but when I am inserting carousel code within modal body, its displaying all the images. 
Here is the snippet of my code

```
<div id="chartImageModal" class="modal fade">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</buttom>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div id="myCarousel" class="container-fluid carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="5000">
                                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                                </ol>
                                <div class="carousel-inner">
                                    <div class="item active">
                                        <img class="img-responsive" src="resources/img1.jpg" alt="slide1">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="item">
                                        <img class="img-responsive" src="resources/img2.jpg" alt="slide1">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Please make sure not have same id for other carousel myCarousel. if yes make myCarousel-1

Comment: Checked.....every ID is unique

Comment: can you please share screen short or maybe code on codepen to debug?